# Array of Objects not being received as an Array node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, request, javascript-objects

I am passing a POST that includes an array of "wines". The object on the send looks line. However when I log the request on the server side, the array is a collection of keys and values. What am I missing:

**** MY TEST REQUESTING CODE ****

```
request.post("http://localhost:3000/todos", {form: params}, function(err, response){
    console.log(response.body);
})
```

**** THE OPTION AS IT IS BEING SENT ****

```
var params = {
    name: 'Test Do',
    summary: 'This is the summary',
    wines: ['56ad66897070ffc5387352dc', '56dg66898180ffd6487353ef']
}
```

**** MY SERVER SIDE CODE --- SHORTEN FOR BREVITY ***

```
exports.todoPost = function(req, res){
console.log(req.body);
var todo = new ToDo(req.body);
    todo.save(function(err, todoX){
        if(err){return res.send.err;}
        console.log(req.body.store_config)
        if(todo.wines){
```

**** THE OUTPUT OF 'console.log(req.body) ****

```
{ name: 'Test Do',
  summary: 'This is the summary',
  'wines[0]': '56ad66897070ffc5387352dc',
  'wines[1]': '56dg66898180ffd6487353ef' }
```

Can I not send an array in a POST? Everything I see online and everything I've tried isn't working. It says I'm passing stuff correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you did send an array using POST. They're just handled differently. One thing you could do instead is send the object as a JSON string.

```
request.post("...", { form: JSON.stringify(params) }, function( ...
```

Then on the server-side, just undo the stringifying by using `JSON.parse`.

```
var params = JSON.parse(req.body);
```

Comment: Is there a way to handle that array as it is received currently? When I console log (todos.wines) or (todos.wines[0]) both come back as null.

Comment: @KJCarlson There are. If you're using Express you can install the body-parser module and that should automatically handle converting it to an array. Otherwise, you'll need to either filter out the key names or do the conversion yourself. (Note: try `todos['wines[0]'] ` and you'll get what you want but it won't be in an array.)

Comment: Thanks, @Mike-C. I realized I was trying to call it after I had already cast it to the model instead of pulling out the variable from the req.body['wines[0]']